# Unable to locate package winehq-stable

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, software-installation, wine

When attempting to install Wine, Terminal answers about the wrong path:

```
E: Unable to locate package winehq-stable
```

**BUT** 
it was installed:

```
anatoly@anatoly-desktop:~$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
Reading package lists... Done
```

Please how to tell Terminal to go to its place?

```
anatoly@anatoly-desktop:~$ wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
--2019-02-28 11:00:11--  https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
Resolving dl.winehq.org (dl.winehq.org)... 151.101.14.217
Connecting to dl.winehq.org (dl.winehq.org)|151.101.14.217|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3220 (3.1K) [application/pgp-keys]
Saving to: ‘winehq.key’

winehq.key                 100%[========================================>]   3.14K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2019-02-28 11:00:12 (13.4 MB/s) - ‘winehq.key’ saved [3220/3220]

anatoly@anatoly-desktop:~$ sudo apt-key add winehq.key
[sudo] password for anatoly: 
OK
anatoly@anatoly-desktop:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                     
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
270 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
anatoly@anatoly-desktop:~$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package winehq-stable
anatoly@anatoly-desktop:~$
```

Comment: Check your mirror is up-to-date (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors)   The only mirror I see for Israel (IL being your country) is listed as *last-update-unknown* meaning it could be a mirror problem. If karel's possible duplicate link doesn't help, I'd suggest moving from your country mirror to the main archive.ubuntu.com site.

Comment: @guiverc This shouldn’t be the main problem here since `winehq-stable` is not in the Ubuntu repositories. OP should switch to an up-to-date mirror though.

Comment: "270 packages can be upgraded" should be addressed before installing anything.

Comment: Were you satisfied with my answer? Then please give me an upvote (▲). If I could solve your problem, it would be nice if you [accepted](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) my answer (✓). In the opposite case, please clarify your needs using [edit]ing or comments. See also https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to have skipped the `apt-add-repository` command. You only added the key of the WineHQ repository as trusted (`apt-key add`) but haven’t added the repository itself, so APT is still unable to find the package `winehq-stable` which resides in this repository. In the [WineHQ guide](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu), the relevant command is listed in a table and not formatted as code – which might be misleading.

According to your `apt update` output, your Ubuntu version is 18.04 (Bionic), so running this should be the right option for you<sup>1</sup>:

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
```

After this, you should be ready to run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

> **BUT** it was installed:
>
> ```
> anatoly@anatoly-desktop:~$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
> Reading package lists... Done
> ```

Not yet… The lines

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
```

inform you about the progress in loading the package database. However, this procedure finished with an error (`E:`) in your case and the package has not been installed.

---

<sup>1</sup> You could also use an universal version of the `apt-add-repository` command which [fills in your release name automatically](http://ask.xmodulo.com/find-ubuntu-version-codename-shell-script.html):

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ $(lsb_release -c | cut -f2) main"
```